# Bluemix connecting to external SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, cloud, integration, ibm-cloud

I have an application built using the ASP.NET 5 runtime - I would like to connect it to an on-premise SQL Server Database.

After some research I've already created the user-provided service with the relevant credentials, however I am unsure what to do next (i.e. writing the necessary code connecting it in ASP.NET).

Some further googling suggests to use Secure Gateway? but is this the only way? the cloud I am working on is dedicated and does not have the Secure Gateway service. Is there a workaround for this?

(Note: The application I'm working on is based on the ASP.NET-Cloudant example on IBM Github, if that helps).

https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/asp.net5-cloudant

Comment: Hey Frank, thank you for the post. To confirm, you have a Dedicated Bluemix environment and you want to connect to an On-Prem MS SQL Server Database on the internal network? In your Dedication Bluemix environment you do not have the Secure Gateway Service, correct?Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @HobertBushIII spot on! thats exactly what the situation is. I'm able to create the user-provided service and pretty much clueless from here on

Answer (score 1):

The Secure Gateway service isn't required as long as the Bluemix environment can connect to the server running SQL Server.  This might require your firewall rules to be a little more relaxed on the SQL Server, or you can contact IBM to create a secure tunnel as [Hobert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4821216/hobert-bush-iii) suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37172435/2522249).

Aside from that issue, if you're planning to use Entity Framework to connect to your SQL Server, it should work similar to the [existing tutorials](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/getting-started.html) on the asp.net site.  The only difference will be in how you access the environment variables to create your connection string.

Assuming that you created your user-provided service with a command similar to this:

`cf cups my-sql-server -p '{"server":"127.0.0.1","database":"MyDB","user":"sa","password":"my-password"}'`

Your connection string in your `Startup.cs` file's `ConfigureServices` method would then look something like this:

```
string vcapServices = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VCAP_SERVICES");
string connection = "";
if (vcapServices != null)
{
    string myServiceName = "my-sql-server";

    JArray userServices = (JArray)JObject.Parse(vcapServices)?["user-provided"];
    dynamic creds = ((dynamic)userServices
      .FirstOrDefault(m => ((dynamic)m).name == myServiceName))?.credentials;

    connection = string.Format(@"Server={0};Database={1};User Id={2}; Password={3};",
      creds.server, creds.database, creds.user, creds.password);
}
```

**Update**

The cloudant boilerplate that you're modifying doesn't use Entity Framework because cloudant is a NoSQL database, so it's a bit different than connecting to SQL Server.  The reason that the boilerplate calls `.Configure` to register the `creds` class is that it needs to use that class from another location, but when using Entity Framework you simply need to use the credentials when adding EF to the services in the `Startup.cs` file so you don't need to use `.Configure<creds>`.

If you follow the guide [here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html), the only part you'll need to change is the line `var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNet5.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";` replacing it with the code above to create the `connection` string instead of hard-coding it like they did in the example tutorial.

Eventually, your `ConfigureServices` method should look something like this, assuming your `DbContext` class is named `BloggingContext` like in the example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string vcapServices = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VCAP_SERVICES");
    string connection = "";
    if (vcapServices != null)
    {
        string myServiceName = "my-sql-server";

        JArray userServices = (JArray)JObject.Parse(vcapServices)?["user-provided"];
        dynamic creds = ((dynamic)userServices
          .FirstOrDefault(m => ((dynamic)m).name == myServiceName))?.credentials;

        connection = string.Format(@"Server={0};Database={1};User Id={2}; Password={3};",
          creds.server, creds.database, creds.user, creds.password);
    }
    services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

And then your `Startup` method would be simplified to:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: true);
    Configuration = configBuilder.Build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've modified the code accordingly but im not sure if its on the right track. Please let me know either Daniel or @Hobert
https://imgur.com/a/XNkot

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify some things, most of the code in the cloudant boilerplate isn't required for using Entity Framework Core to connect to SQL Server.  Specifically, the call to `.Configure`, the `creds` class, and setting values in `Configuration` are not required when using EntityFramework.

Comment: Ah. so I'm assuming the original code block in Startup can be commented out. 
(Edit: saw the edit, thanks for the clarification)
here's the modified ConfigureServices method
http://imgur.com/ay2hKym

Does anything from the Controller need to be modified accordingly since now we are connecting to a completely different database?

Comment: you'll need to keep the `services.AddMvc()` line, if you want to use MVC in your project.  I've updated my answer with an example of what the `ConfigureServices` and `Startup` methods should look like.  The `DbController` controller won't be used now since you're using Entity Framework to manage the database connection, following the guides on the Entity Framework documentation pages should get you started on accessing the DB using Entity Framework.

Comment: Sounds great! this should be more than enough to keep me busy ;)

(Just peaking a little into the future) Based on the way we wrote the startup class (where i see that we only stored 1 set of credentials), is there any way (as nonsense as this would sound) that the data in the on-prem SQL Server can be pulled into any one of Bluemix database (in this case, the only one we offer is Cloudant, MySQL and Postgres to come), such that the SQL Server and Cloudant can both be used by the application?

Comment: You can certainly use both SQL Server and Cloudant in the same application, if you wanted to do that you'd just need to add the code to add Entity Framework to services and leave the existing code for connecting to Cloudant in the boilerplate.  This would let you access your data in the SQL Server through the configured `DbContext` class and still let you access your Cloudant data through the `DbController` class like the boilerplate does now.

Comment: Ah I see. so both DB s will be added to the services object (like how it uses a Builder pattern to add services), but then would I need separate Controllers for that? 
(haven't finished the Entity Framework tutorial so I'll just assume we need a controller for the SQL Server)

Comment: You don't need a controller for the SQL Server, the only reason there is a controller for the Cloudant DB is that the boilerplate accesses the Cloudant DB through a web api provided by that controller.  The SQL Server will be accessed by injecting your `DbContext` class into the constructor of your existing controller (ex: your `HomeController`).

Answer (score 0):

Excellent!

1. In Public Bluemix Regions, you would create and use the Secure Gateway Service to access the On-Premise MS SQL Server DB.
2. In your case, as a Bluemix Dedicated client, you should engage your IBM Bluemix Administration Team so they can work with your Network Team to create a tunnel between the Dedicated Bluemix Region and your On-Premise MS SQL DB Server.

Comment: hmmm is there anything specific I need to talk to the Bluemix team?
Does that mean:
1. they offer the Secure Gateway Service, OR
2. there is a workaround that requires their intervention?

Comment: Exactly, it's number 2. You would need to their assistance to implement a tunnel to the On-Premise DB

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect directly from your Asp.Net Core application to a SQL Server you actually don't need a Secure Gateway.

For example, if you want to use a SQL Azure as your Database you can simply add the given connection string in your application.

But, for pratical and security reasons, you should create a User-Provided Service to store your credentials (and not use statically in your code), and pull your credentials from you VCAP_SERVICES simply adding SteelToe to your Cconfiguration Builder. (Instead of use parse the configuration manually with JObjects and JArrays)

Step-by-step:

1. In your CloudFoundry console create a User-Provided Service using a Json:

`cf cups MySqlServerCredentials -p '{"server":"tcp:example.database.windows.net,1433", "database":"MyExampleDatabase", "user":"admin", "password":"password"}'`

Obs.: If you use Windows console/Powershell you should escape you double quotes in Json like:

`'{\"server\":\"myserver\",\"database\":\"mydatabase\",\"user\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"password\"}'`

2. After you have created your User-Provided Service you should Connect this Service with your application in Bluemix Console.
3. Then, In your application add the reference to SteelToe CloudFoundry `Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundry`
4. In your Startup class add:

   ```
   using Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration;
   ...
   var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(basePath)
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")                    
       .AddCloudFoundry();      
   var config = builder.Build();
   ```
5. Finally, to access your configurations just use:

   ```
   var mySqlName = config["vcap:services:user-provided:0:name"];
   var database  = config["vcap:services:user-provided:0:credentials:database"];
   var server    = config["vcap:services:user-provided:0:credentials:server"];
   var password  = config["vcap:services:user-provided:0:credentials:password"];
   var user      = config["vcap:services:user-provided:0:credentials:user"];
   ```

OBS.: If you're using Azure, remember to configure your Database firewall to accept the IP of your Bluemis application, but as default Bluemix don't give a static IP address you have some options:

- Buy a Bluemix Statica service to you application (expensive)
- Update firewall rules with REST put with the current IP of application (workaroud)
- Open your Azure Database Firewall to a broad range of IPs. (Just DON'T)

More info about SteelToe CloudFoundry in :
https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Configuration/tree/master/src/Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundry